# What to do about a solid wall?

Tags: insulation, building-regulations

A little over a year ago I had a first floor extension added to my house (London, UK), and I have since discovered a number of problems - for example, no insulation at all in the loft. I am now having some more work done by another builder - a small, rear extension, with the demolition of an exterior wall under the earlier, first floor extension. In the process of inserting a steel beam over the new opening, they have made the appropriate holes in the wall of the first floor extension for the supports while demolishing the wall, and they discovered that the wall of the first floor extension is built without a cavity - it is basically just the two 'skins' right up against each other.

This was passed by a private building inspector company (I've checked their credentials online and they seem to be genuine), and I have their certificate. However, as far as I can see from the building regulations here, this should never have been passed - what do people here think?

The other, more practical question is, what can I do to make this legal, or at least avoid problems with poor insulation, humidity etc?

Adding a picture where I think you can just about see the problem:

[image]

***Edit***

To answer the questions in the comments:

- The wall consists of an outser brick skin and breezeblocks on the inside.
- My current builder says it isn't legal because the building code requires an outer wall to have a 10cm cavity which is filled with approved insulation material.
- The council does indeed have inspectors, but our builders provide their own, private building inspector, who seems to be rather more thorough than the one used by the previous builder.

Comment: What is the wall made out of...? Is it structural? Who says it is not legal...why? Is it an exterior wall that needs to be insulated by Code? (It’s not a “party wall” ?)

Comment: What does the new company say about this construction? Is there a local building council that you could have take a look at it? While there are people here with broad knowledge from all over the world, your local regulators are going to be the ones who will know your local codes/laws better than anyone here.

Comment: I agree with Lee that looks like concrete why do you think it would not be legal? Contacting your local building codes division would be better than the limited information we have here.

Comment: Based on your updates, I'd recommend that you have a city inspector take a look at the work. Since it doesn't seem to have been done to code, then the initial builder _and_ the private inspection company should both be held liable for doing and allowing inferior work. If the inspector allowed this to happen, who knows what other shortcuts the builder took that the inspector overlooked.

Comment: I definitely do not know buiding regs, but if it was a first-floor only extension, then the thickness of the wall may have been limited by the wall underneath it. i.e. you can't build a 300mm thick wall on top of a 200mm thick one. While new walls on new foundations must be cavity walls, regs will make allowances for walls built on top of existing walls.